# What is top level and Implementation level?

Tags: javascript

I am new to programming and have been reading JavaScript online at Mozilla Developer Network. Through my reading they have mentioned “top level” and “Implementation level”. Can someone explain that to me please?

Comment: It would be helpful if you [edit]ed your question to include some links to the articles you’re referring to.

Comment: There's a "top level scope" or so, but "implementation level" is just completely ambiguous without context.